# Symlinked binary permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, mount

I have 2 disk, one for root/home directory, one for big files

I tried to move then symlink `/home/asd/go` to `/media/asd/team512/go` and it works normally (can be `ls`, size are correct)

```bsh
cd ~
ls -al | grep go
lrwxrwxrwx  1 asd  asd         21 Mar  5 12:33 go -> /media/asd/team512/go

ls -al ~/go/bin | grep air
-rwxr-xr-x 1 asd asd   2326528 Feb  3 15:22 air
```

But when I tried to execute it, it shows error:

```
which air
air not found

~/go/bin/air                                                                    
zsh: permission denied: /home/asd/go/bin/air
```

It seems because my fstab is without `exec` option,
i've added the `exec` option, how do I remount it without `unmount`/rebooting?

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/b1080dbf-dad1-4652-8e82-xxx /media/asd/team512 ext4 noatime,user,exec 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind found the answer, from modifying this https://askubuntu.com/questions/175739/how-do-i-remount-a-filesystem-as-read-write

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw,user,exec,noatime /dev/disk/by-uuid/xxx /media/asd/team512
```